# How do I Print/Display Site information Form

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I'm trying to print the Site Information Form, and a series of other forms in the near future, inside a lightbox using a snippet of code I found similar to the following.

global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
print user_edit($user);

This, along with some other code not mentioned, will display the user account form. But I'd like to know how do I print the Site Info Form, and any other form I may wish to display in the future? What process or methods can I use to find out what I need to do?

I hope I'm not being too vague. Any pseduo-code, suggestions or even a hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php print drupal_get_form('system_site_information_settings'); ?>
```

You can output any form in Drupal using drupal_get_form once you know it's form_id (which is the function name that returns the form array)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at the answer provided at - [Theming the node edit forms  to open them within Lightbox](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2709/theming-the-node-edit-forms-to-open-them-within-lightbox) - You can use [popups](http://drupal.org/project/popups) module to display and work with any form in a lightbox like popup which u can theme.

Comment: Did I totally get the question wrong, wondering why the answer was downvoted?